# Simple IOS Application

Tags: ios, iphone

I developed an IOS appliacton which have only 1 button then i created a zip file from .app file in mac and then upload this file to [Online IOS Simulator](https://appetize.io/upload), but after uploading my application is not loading it only shows icon when i click it shows splash screen then close. Thanks in Advance

https://appetize.io/app/24ax4d3c9zy1ej5jzqfc398t38

Comment: Did you try run on simulator (on mac) or device with release build configuration?

Comment: Yes, On Mac it is running fine

Comment: also it is running fine on device but only for 7-days after 7-days app show splash screen and then closed.

Comment: App show output then closed, https://appetize.io/app/m6grnew31kv8qz4h38macmff0m

Answer (score 0):

In Appetize pricing part say that app free for 100 minutes/month so may your first 100 minutes finished , if you have paid apple developer so you can export ipa with adhoc distribution and upload it on http://diawi.com and you will can run it on device .

Comment: but i did't used it for 100 minutes, my app was not working when i upload it first time.